# VC toolset version mismatched in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

When I compiling a C++ project with newly installed VS2017, I got fatal error C1902.
Then I checked Common7\IDE and VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64 for the versions of my toolset, then I found some version mismatches.

[image: 25019]
**14.10.25019** in VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64 (HostX86\x86 is the same)

[image: 25017]
**14.10.25017** in Common7\IDE

[image: Project Settings]
**Project Settings**

I can't fix the error by simply copy and replace the files, so how can I fix this?

Comment: Nobody remembers VS errors by number.

Comment: @HansPassant The option in project settings only contains two alternative toolsets: **Visual Studio 2017 (v141)/Visual Studio 2017 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141_clang_c2)**, and I can't specify the version for them.

Comment: @n.m. fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation. The version mismatches of the binaries cause the problem.

Comment: Edit your question to include them, not post them in comments... Also, I'd recommend you to use either the VS frontend (v141) or the Clang frontend (v141_clang), but don't mix them.

Comment: @tambre: I'm using MSVC compiler only, Clang/C2 is just another option. The screenshot of my project settings is added.

Comment: I would simply un-install VS and any other similar compilers you may have (.NET, Win7 SDK), then install what I need from scratch.  I've had issues like this quite often with MSVC and I've found that it's not worth the time trying to repair the installation manually.

Comment: @Stewart: I've tried reinstalling VS over and over again... But this error still occurs... I also found that almost all of the tools have a version of 25019 in 25017 folder, but I'm not using preview version.

Comment: Make sure to try to update through the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: @tambre Reinstallation is not working, but I solved this by the method shown in my own answer below, thanks.